# Read XML from local resource in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : Reading XML from local resource (for testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111735/android-reading-xml-from-local-resource-for-testing)

I have an application in Android which is read list and urls of genres from a XML file.
In the 1st phase I should read this XML from local resource and in next phase I should do it from a web service or something.
This is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<genres>
    <genre>
        <id>1</id>    
        <title>Action</title>
        <count>5</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/action-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>2</id>    
        <title>Adventure</title>
        <count>12</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/adventure-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>3</id>    
        <title>Comedies</title>
        <count>54</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/comedy-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>4</id>    
        <title>Crime</title>
        <count>2</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/crime-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>5</id>    
        <title>Dramas</title>
        <count>3</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/drama-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>6</id>    
        <title>Epics</title>
        <count>1</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/epics-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>7</id>    
        <title>Horror</title>
        <count>0</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/horror-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>8</id>    
        <title>Musical</title>
        <count>0</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/musicals-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>9</id>    
        <title>Sci-fi</title>
        <count>5</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/scifi-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>10</id>    
        <title>War</title>
        <count>12</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/war-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <id>11</id>    
        <title>Westerns</title>
        <count>0</count>
        <thumb_url>http://www.filmsite.org/images/westerns-genre.jpg</thumb_url>
    </genre>
</genres>`
```

First I put this XML in value folder but it gets error and said "Invalid XML" or something.
Then I googled whole internet and I found that I should create folder and name it row then put this file in row folder and after that import it like:

```
Xml.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.genres.xml), 
    Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
```

but when I create this folder it gets error and doesn't work. And also if you close the Eclipse it wont open till you delete row folder.
The problem is I want to read a XML file from local resource but I don't know where to put the file and how to quickly read and parse it. Please help me with this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The folder for RAW resources is named 'raw' not 'row'

Comment: *what error* do you get?

Comment: I don't know what happened but Eclipse doesn't work anymore! I closed it but it wont open anymore. I'm on Ubuntu and I don't know what should I do now? :(